# RxJava use dynamic variable with interval

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

On my RxJava code, I create an Observable with an interval. The code look like this :

```
public class GetProducts implements RxRequest<Observable<ProductsResult>> {

    private LatLng markerLocationToReport;

    private static int TIMER = 5;

    private static GetProducts INSTANCE = new GetProducts();

    public static GetProducts getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private Observable obs;

    private GetProducts() {
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<ProductsResult> getObservable() {
        if (obs == null) {
            obs = Observable.interval(0, TIMER, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
                    .flatMap((tick) -> Observable.just(GetProductsRequest.getProducts(markerLocationToReport)))
                    .retry()
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).publish();
            ((ConnectableObservable) obs).connect();
        }
        return obs;
    }

    public void setMarkerLocationToReport(LatLng markerLocationToReport) {
        this.markerLocationToReport = markerLocationToReport;
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I use the current value of `markerLocationToReport` in my `flatMap` function ?
Because in the current code when the request is made by `GetProductsRequest.getProducts(markerLocationToReport)`  always use the initial value of `markerLocationToReport` when the `Observable` have been created and I need to update it during my app lifecycle.

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I see a couple of races: 1) `markerLocationToReport` should be volatile so the function of `flatMap` can observe it properly; 2) unless you call `getObservable` from a single thread, it may create multiple instances of the timed action.

In addition, you can use convenience `.publish().autoConnect(0)` which will connect immediately and you don't have to cast to `ConnectableObservable`.

Comment: Good to know, I tried with `volatile` but when I update my variable it stay null when I enter to the getProduct() method

Comment: That's odd. You sure the lambda captured the right variable?

Comment: Finally the volatile works. My coworker didn't tell me everything. So thank you